# What is this でも

Tags: words, reading-comprehension, particle-でも

A: 課長、すみません。お願いがあるのですが、少々お時間よろしいですか。

昨日、ビジネスマナーのセミナーの案内が来ました / 案内を受けとりました。仕事に必要なことを教えてもらえるので、参加したいのですが…。
セミナーの場所が遠く、費用も高いので、会社の費用で行かせていただけませんか。

B: ああ、費用は本当に高いね。これを会社で出してもらえるとは思えないなあ。

A: ……。では半額だけ**でも**会社が費用を出してくれるといいのですが…。残りは / もう半分は私が出しますので。

B: じゃあ / では、そうしよう。

I marked it in bold. 
This is a composition of mine where I received some feedback/corrections on a forum. 
I'm not sure about this でも. 
does it mean "or something" here? "The company pays only half the sum or something..." ?

Answer (score 4):

でも can be used in a few ways as you can see in the dictionary, but the one you are looking for now is **even/also**.

Basically, he is saying that

> **even** half the amount would be appreciated.
>   half the amount would **also** be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> で-も ㊁〘副助詞〙
>   ❽ 《少量を表す語について》肯定表現で、せめてそのくらいの意を表す。「少し**でも**分けてやりたい」

The でも in your example means "at least".

半額だけ**でも** = just half the amount, *at least*.

An example from Shogakukan's Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary:

> １巻だけ**でも**印刷したらよかったのに。
>   We should have printed the first volume, *at least*.